# External USB-HDD became /dev/sda after power off, how to pin it to /dev/sdc?

Tags: ubuntu, devices, external-hdd

Today a fuse blew out which turned off a small server.

This server has an USB-HDD connected to it, but since I connected it about 3-4 months ago, I never turned the server totally off (no electricity), but only issued an occasional `sudo reboot`.

This USB-HDD was listed under `/dev/sdc`, so I had a mounted partition via `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/hdd5-usb-1`.

There's also a mounted SSD at `/dev/sdb`, so that the correct `fdisk -l` looks as follows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ece66

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 500117503 499615746 238.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 500117503 499615744 238.2G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CD3F3DA1-2901-45A0-B6E9-2BEEA36F3E78

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1000214527 1000212480  477G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/n3150--vg-root: 222.4 GiB, 238769143808 bytes, 466345984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/n3150--vg-swap_1: 15.9 GiB, 17028874240 bytes, 33259520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 4.6 TiB, 5000981077504 bytes, 9767541167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0B9E1A83-476F-47AE-8234-2D29497F55CA

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 9767541133 9767539086  4.6T Linux filesystem
```

After the power outage and the following automatic boot of the server the entries looked like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 4.6 TiB, 5000981077504 bytes, 9767541167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0B9E1A83-476F-47AE-8234-2D29497F55CA

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 9767541133 9767539086  4.6T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ece66

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       501758 500117503 499615746 238.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       501760 500117503 499615744 238.2G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdc: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CD3F3DA1-2901-45A0-B6E9-2BEEA36F3E78

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 1000214527 1000212480  477G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/n3150--vg-root: 222.4 GiB, 238769143808 bytes, 466345984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/n3150--vg-swap_1: 15.9 GiB, 17028874240 bytes, 33259520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Obviously this had some pretty nasty issues since the database on the SSD at the expected `/dev/sdb1`~`/media/ssd1` was suddenly presented the boot partition, and what was believed to be the USB HDD was actually the mounted SSD.

How can I prevent something like this happening ever again? How can I "pin" a hardware to a specific `/dev/sd*` entry?

Comment: If you really really need to use `/dev/sd*` for your devices instead of labels, uuid, etc. first thing coming to mind is udev rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not attempt to get a fixed `/dev/sdX` name at all. You should just not use such a name directly.

What you should do is reference your disk (or disk's partition) by an autodetected identifier provided under `/dev/disk/`. Among the choices available there, `/dev/disk/by-id/` has entries tied to the serial number of a disk device. So even two identical disks can be differenciated without ambiguity. Note that all the entries in the `/dev/disk/` tree are just symlinks to the actual `/dev/sdX` entries, but as you discovered, they can be dynamic: the order of apparition or detection on the system does matter for `/dev/sdX`, it won't matter for `/dev/disk/` (or at least for `/dev/disk/by-id/`).

Some of the entries there have an equivalent `/etc/fstab` syntax. `LABEL= UUID= PARTUUID= PARTLABEL=` match their equivalent `/dev/disk/by-{label,uuid,partlabel,partuuid}/`. Here's what [`fstab(5)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/fstab.5.html) manpage tells:

> `LABEL=<label>` or `UUID=<uuid>` may be given instead of a device name.
>   This is the recommended method, as **device names are often a
>   coincidence of hardware detection order, and can change when other
>   disks are added or removed**. For example, `LABEL=Boot` or
>   `UUID=3e6be9de-8139-11d1-9106-a43f08d823a6`. (Use a
>   filesystem-specific tool like e2label(8), xfs_admin(8), or fatlabel(8)
>   to set LABELs on filesystems).

Here's an interesting Archlinux wiki page about these entries:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming